# How to choose between MongoDB and PostgreSQL for GIS?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, gis, postgis, database

I'm trying to find some information on this topic but most articles I'm finding are 3+ years old.  I am also fairly new to this side of things and not sure who to ask.

For my particular use case, I'm not a database expert at all but I've used MongoDB a few times before.  I have only used PostgreSQL once for a small project (no GIS stuff involved).  For what its worth, I have a small amount of data right now that I've stored into dynamoDB.  There's a geo library for it, but it is only available in Java and I don't know Java very well.

My use case is fairly simple - besides user profile data, I want to be able to query markers added by users.  Markers within X miles of a authenticated user's current `latLng`, etc.  Markers have other data besides `latLng` associated with them, such as the user who added it, title, description, etc.

My goal is to be able to return results to the client side with markers within X miles in their current location from nearest to farthest using a web API.  For this, between Mongo and PostgreSQL, what would be better to start with?

Comment: You don't need a special database for this, though it will be faster in databases with geo extensions. You can just use [the Haversine formula](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27928/472495). There are SQL implementations in which you can add a distance filter in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**PostgreSQL** can give you full (geo)spatial functionalities via [PostGis](http://www.postgis.net), although you may *not* need that much in your application.

If you need just to quickly find users within a certain radius of a (lat, lng) point, you can use the [earthdistance module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/earthdistance.html), together with [GIST indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gist-intro.html).

Check [How can I speed-up my query on geo-location processes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158349/how-can-i-speed-up-my-query-on-geo-location-processes/158422#158422) for detailed explanations.

Check also [Searching in a Radius using Postgres](https://johanndutoit.net/searching-in-a-radius-using-postgres/).

---

In **MongoDB**, you would use [geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/) functionality and [2dsphere Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/)

---

Querys in PostgreSQL are very fast and very flexible, and they scale very well. You need a little bit more of work to set it up than you would with MongoDB.

Anyhow, the basic functionality is available in both, and you should decide considering all other factors:

- Is your data well structured, and with few variations within this structure? (more on SQL side)
- Do you need ACID (atomicity, consistency, isolation, durability) guarantees? (more on SQL side)
- Do you need huge horizontal scaling? (more on MongoDB side)
- Do you need to query several tables at once (and join)? (SQL side)
- Do you feel more comfortable with JavaScript and JSON than in any other languages? (MongoDB +)
- (etc., etc.)

Check also [Postgres Outperforms MongoDB and Ushers in New Developer Reality](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-plus-edb-blog/marc-linster/postgres-outperforms-mongodb-and-ushers-new-developer-reality) and [System Properties Comparison MongoDB vs. PostgreSQL](http://db-engines.com/en/system/MongoDB%3BPostgreSQL), among many others.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joanolo.  I realize my question was downvoted a lot, but to be honest it is pretty hard to find this kind of information easily and also simple enough to digest.  I appreciate your response.

Comment: If I may ask one more question.  At the moment, I don't think I need relational database, and hence am leaning towards MongoDB due to the ease of setting it up and using it.  I am expecting a lot of initial writes (new markers created) and lots of reads, but don't expect many updates to existing markers besides deletes.  I think my data models are also simple enough that if the need arises (and as mentioned I don't know much about databases, I'm tryign to build a PoC) I can switch to postgres.  Do you think that is a valid approach?  Thanks

Comment: When you're on a Proof of Concept, normally your basic need is *make it happen fast*, in that case, choose the tools that let you work fastest. That depends a lot on your previous background; the kind of tools you're accostumed to. But be careful and don't fall into the trap of thinking that what's best for a PoC is the best thing in production...

Comment: geoNear, and geoIntersects can be used in regards to MongoDB